# Comparing Values of 5s and 7% Notes (Security Analysis by Benjamin Graham)

Tags: valuation, bond-yields, value-investing

I was reading Security Analysis by Benjamin Graham (Sixth Edition). Page 63, last paragraph says:

> A third kind of analytical conclusion may be illustrated by a
>   comparison of Interborough RapidTransit Company First and Refunding 5s
>   with the same company’s Collateral 7% Notes, when both issues were
>   selling at the same price (say 62) in 1933.
>
> The 7% notes were clearly
>   worth considerably more than the 5s. Each \$1,000 note was secured by
>   deposit of \$1,736 face amount of 5s; the principal of the notes had
>   matured; they were entitled either to be paid off in full or to a sale of the
>   collateral for their benefit. The annual interest received on the collateral
>   was equal to about $87 on each 7% note (which amount was actually 
>   being distributed to the note holders), so that the current income on the 
>   7s was considerably greater than that on the 5s. Whatever technicalities 
>   might be invoked to prevent the note holders from asserting their con- 
>   tractual rights promptly and completely, it was difficult to imagine 
>   conditions under which the 7s would not be intrinsically worth consid- 
>   erably more than the 5s.

The 1,736 statement puzzled me. Is it a statement or a quick calculation? I assume that `5%` and `7%` is referring to the annual yield rate. Thus, if the latter is bought for $\$1000$, then after a year it will grow to $\$1070$. To have the same result, the former should be bought as $\$1070\div 1.05\approx\$1019 $, which is nowhere near the value in the statement.

Comment: In bond jargon "5s" refers to bonds with a 5% **coupon** not yield.

Comment: Note that he is comparing (his opinion of) "intrinsic value" not market value. He does not assume that they are necessarily the same. He believes the 7% have better instrinsic value because of their collateral.

Comment: I see. Thus, the statement '$\$1000$ notes against  $\$1736$' is not calculated from 5% and 7% coupon, right?

Comment: Right. He got that figure from some other source, perhaps the bond prospectus or company reports.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

A &5 note of worth \$1000, is issued against a collateral of 5% bond of worth \$1736. Now yearly interest of \$1736 at a rate of 5% comes \$87. This interest is distributed among note holders. So note holder effective get a interest of 8.7% (=87/1000 x 100) which is much better than 7% as per contract. This is the advantage note holders were getting

------I think this will clarify your query : Kashinath